# the value of sizeof('0') is how much?

Tags: c, char, sizeof, literals

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char c = '0';
    printf("%d %d",sizeof(c), sizeof('0'));
    return 0;
}
```

I expect the output is 1 1.but the real result is 1 4.

Comment: `'0'` is an integer.

Comment: `sizeof()` returns a `size_t`, which is properly printed with `%zu`.  Printing `size_t` with `%d` is undefined behavior.

Comment: You would have been fond of a DSP I once worked with, it had `CHAR_BIT == 16` and `sizeof(char) == sizeof(int)` – on *this* machine, you would have received the output you expected...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Character literals (`'0'`, `'a'`, `'d'`, `'.'`) in C are of type `int` (unlike in C++, where they are of type `char`).

So you will get in C:

```
sizeof(char) == 1
sizeof('0')  == sizeof(int) // note that this is not necessarily 4!
```

whereas in C++ you will have:

```
sizeof(char) == 1
sizeof('0')  == sizeof(char)
```

Answer (score 4):

Opposite to C++ in C (integer) character constants have the type `int`.

From the C Standard (6.4.4.4 Character constants)

> 10 An integer character constant **has type int**.

Compare the quote with the quote from the C++17 Standard (5.13.3 Character literals)

> 2 A character literal that does not begin with u8, u, U, or L is an
>   ordinary character literal. An ordinary character literal that
>   contains a single c-char representable in the execution character set
>   **has type char**, with value equal to the numerical value of the encoding of the c-char in the execution character set....

As for this expression

```
sizeof(c)
```

then it provides the size of an object of the type `char`. Objects of the type `char` always have the size equal to `1`.

From the C Standard (6.5.3.4 The sizeof and alignof operators)

> 4 When sizeof is applied to an operand that has type char, unsigned
>   char, or signed char, (or a qualified version thereof) the result is
>   1....

Pay attention to that a valid call of the function printf will look like

```
printf("%zu %zu",sizeof(c), sizeof('0'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sizeof('0')
```

is actually

`sizeof(ASCII value of '0')`

which is integer. Thus it is printing `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: Not in Klingon or EBCDIC computers :)

Comment: @pmg When will these systems go extinct?

Comment: @machine_1 When `std::sentient` is added to the C++ STL.